# want to create a public box but only display one line of text only?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I am newbie with Rails and trying to make a page which can input something like video, photo and then output them into a page. I am trying to make a public button like a condition for this one.

And here is what I did.

At first I have some code at app -> view -> courses -> form.html.erb like this

```
<div class="field">
<%= form.text_field :image %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= form.text_field :video %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= form.text_field :title %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= form.text_field :star %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= form.text_field :description %>
</div>
```

I went to app -> view -> courses -> form.html.erb and write some code to make a public button like this

```
<div class="field">
<%= form.check_box :public, id: :public, class: "filled-in"  %>
<label for="public">Public</label>    
</div>
```

To make this code run, I went to controller -> concerns -> courses_controller.rb and wrote some code like this

```
def course_params
  params.require(:course).permit(:image, :video, :title, :star, :description, :public)
end
```

And I went to app -> controllers -> concerns -> pages_controller.rb and wrote something like this

```
def home
@courses = Course.where(public: true)
end
```

But as you can see in this image [Image for this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaBvt.png) I can only write the name of the button, not the button, I mean I can not click to the button yet.

Here is what they design, I must make the check box which I can click to that

[Design photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fijkx.png)

I am very confusing with this problem. Could you please explain for me about this problem ? And tell me about the solution of this case ? Thank you very much.

Comment: You used form.check_box for the field and you want it to be clickable button? or am i missing something?

Comment: @AmeerHamza thank you for your comment, I want to make a check_box and when I click to this check box, the condition will be true and I can display something.

Comment: ok i understand. Can you please share your form code, so i can go through it.

Comment: and also for instance try removing id , class and label like this
<%= f.check_box :public %>

Comment: @AmeerHamza thank you very much. I added the code I wrote to the form.html.erb and also the code I wrote to the pages_controller.rb too, to make the button run. Do you have some idea for me ?